# PHP regular expression to extract TwitPic link/code if present

Tags: php, regex

I would like to be able to check a string of text and extract a TwitPic URL if it is present in the string, ultimately I would like just the code portion, but either will do.

Example:

```
"blah blah blah http://twitpic.com/1aso4q blah blah"
```

Desired result:

```
http://twitpic.com/1aso4q
```

or

```
1aso4q
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('#http://twitpic.com/(\w+)#', $content, $matches);
```

You will then have all the codes in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex

```
'/http:\/\/twitpic\.com\/\S+/i'
```

Comment: you don't need to enclose \S in square brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "blah blah blah http://twitpic.com/1aso4q blah blah";
$s = explode(" ",$str);
print_r( preg_grep('/http:\/\/twitpic.com/',$s) );
```