# Rails regex to extract Twitpic link/code if present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, twitpic

Provided a url, within a string of text (tweet) such as

**"Check out my twitpic http://twitpic.com/1876544594 its awesome"**

I need a Rails regex that will return 18744594, the id of this particular twitpic...

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515087/php-regex-to-extract-twitpic-link-code-if-present) but was for PHP, and I need it for Rails.

I would **also** be able to pull the name of the site, so the text between http:// and .com "twitpic"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract `18744594` only

```
/http:\/\/twitpic\.com\/(\d+)/
```

To extract `twitpic` and `18744594`

```
/http:\/\/(twitpic)\.com\/(\d+)/
```

Comment: and if the ID was alphanumeric, I would just change the d+ to w+ ?

Comment: Oh.. and the reason i am asking to extract twitpic, is for cases when its NOT twitpic.. i want to know which it is.. so without providing twitpic, i need to know what is between http:// and .com - could be tweetphone or yfrog for instance

Comment: That would be /http:\/\/(\w+)\.com\/(\w+)/ then 'twitpic' would be $1 and 18744594 would be $2.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was late to response. And @Rabbott, yeah `\w+` would be ok for alphanumeric, `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`